# Selenium Unable to locate element from class

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to get 'Administrator' value from my website and this is the element

```
<td align="center" class="okm-DisableSelect">Administrator</td>
```

I copied the xpath using chrome and I got this value

```
/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[6]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[7]
```

I tried this but it gives me error 'Unable to locate element'. What am I doing wrong?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[5]/div[3]/div/div[6]/div/div[4]/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/div/div/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[7]")).getText();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, that XPath is massive which is going to make it very brittle (likely to break). You shouldn't use an XPath that starts at `/html` and you shouldn't really use an XPath that is more than just a few levels deep... maybe 3-5.

Secondly, you haven't given us enough info to see what's wrong with that XPath because it is so huge. Your best bet is to NOT use copy XPath because it generally leads to large, brittle XPaths like this. Ideally you would use CSS selectors instead of XPaths because they are better supported, faster, and easier to craft. You should spend the time to learn how to handcraft them instead of using some tool because they will be shorter and less brittle, if done right.

Given the HTML provided, I would start with a CSS selector like `td.okm-DisableSelect` and see if that works. If it does not, you could fall back to an XPath using the contained text, "Administrator", e.g. `//td[.='Administrator']`. There are, I"m sure, many more options but without more HTML I can't tell you what they would be.